# Rails 5 override dom_id helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, overriding, helper

I have encountered a strange problem. We have a project, in which - for security reasons - we wanted to avoid displaying the id for most of the models. So, instead of having a dom id `user_12`, we wanted to use the serial (`id="user_adsi94zurew"`). First we gave it all manually (like in these two haml lines):

```
.user_line{id: "user_#{@user.serial}"}
= form_for @user, url: user_path(@user), id: {"edit_user_#{@user.serial}"}
```

It is just not nice, we didn't like it. Then I found the helper method `dom_id`, which I overrode in the `application_helper` the following way:

```
def dom_id(record, prefix = nil)
  if record.respond_to?(:serial)
    "#{dom_class(record, prefix)}_#{record.serial}"
  else
    super
  end
end
```

It just worked fine for most of the situations, though I didn't have the time for a thorough testing, because - as our application grew larger - we needed to rewrite it. We changed to **Rails 5.0.0.1** and started to sort our controllers in modules (folders). I copied the code to our new `application_helper.rb`, and I found it was not working (it returned the good old `user_12`). And then I found, it WAS working, and then again, it wasn't. And that was it: it was almost totally random, when or where it worked. I made some tests and found that, when not working, my code was not even run (so it was not that the condition evaluated to `false`), the method went straight into the original `dom_id`, as if mine hadn't existed at all!

Then I found some rules against my theory of random, but these were even stranger:

1.) In the file `/app/views/company_manager/companies/edit.html.haml`, as well as in the `new.html.haml` (same folder) it never works. My first thought was that it is due to the module `CompanyManager`.

2.) In the `root` (`/app/views/landings/landing_page.html.haml`) it worked. Then it didn't! But if I made any change in the helper method (adding a `p 'here'`, or even an **empty new line(!)**), it worked again!

3.) In the partial `/app/views/company_manager/regions/_region.html.haml` (`.region_line{id: dom_id(region)}`) it didn't work, but in the ajax response `update.js.erb` (same folder) it did (at least occasionally). I had some tough ten minutes due to that, because I tried to update region line in the DOM with the following jQuery code: `$('#<%= dom_id(@region) %>').replaceWith('<%= j(render @region) %>');`, and since the `dom_id` returned `region_6` first and `region_hd5j8g6` second, jQuery couldn't find the line to update.

4.) Lastly, we use the [old](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/26/rails-add-helpers-method-to-ease-usage-of-helper-modules-in-controllers.html) way to access helper methods from controllers (which means `include ApplicationHelper` in the ApplicationController). When the method returned `company_31`, I tried to reference it from the controller, and it raised a `NoMethodError`, whereas other helper methods from `ApplicationHelper` were still accessible.

Conclusion: it seems to me that as Rails merges the helper methods it is sometimes my method that overrides the original, and sometimes it is vice versa. If the server is already running, and I make some changes in my method, Rails seems to reload just `application_helper.rb`, so it is my method that is above the original (though it still has no effect on `companies/edit` or `regions/_region`)...

Any ideas? Other explanations? Something, I missed? Any hints?

(Note: With alternatives, thank you, I am well equipped. If there is no solution, I will rename my method to `dom_id_serial` and try to convince `form_for` to use it instead of `dom_id`, or anything. So I am interested in anything that **overrides `dom_id` and works**, or any **reason why it does not**, and nothing else.)

Thanks in advance!